# How can i fix the token in hql?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

how can i fix this select * error? thank you!!

Query query = em.createQuery("select distinct............");

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: *

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    h.cod_1    AS cod1,
    h.cod_2    AS cod2,
    h.cod_3    AS cod3,
    w.stato    AS stato
FROM
    workflow w
    JOIN hist_1 h ON h.id = w.id_riga
    AND h.dt_perio_rif = '202111'
WHERE
        w.id_report = '1'
    AND w.id = (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    w2.id
                FROM
                    workflow w2
                WHERE
                        w2.id_riga = w.id_riga
                    AND w2.id_report = '1'
                ORDER BY
                    w2.update_date DESC
            )
        WHERE
            ROWNUM = 1
    );
```

Comment: well, you are leaving out the important part of the query...

Comment: the query is under :)

Comment: Looks like a native query. Any reason you don't call `createNativeQuery()` then?

Comment: ok thanks it worked with createNativeQuery ()